# Open a NEW page in a pop up instead of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have a `DIV` which opens after the submission of form on `button click`. the div code is below

```
<div id="successmsg" style="font-family: 'signika_negativeregular', sans-serif; font-size: 0.9em;">

                            <div style="height: auto; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #193284; padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; font-size: 15px; background: url(images/common/header-bottom-line.png) no-repeat bottom left; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1.5em;">
                                <div id="divTitle1" runat="server"></div>

                                <div style="width: 434px; margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.7em; text-align: justify; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'signika_negativeRegular', sans-serif; color: #666; margin-top: 10px;">
                                    <div class="readmoreNew2">
                                        We appreciate and acknowledge your interest shown towards RBL Bank.<br />
                                        Our team would get back to you soon.
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <input type="button" id="btnOk" value="OK" class="btnDropbox" style="background: #CF060D; font-family: 'signika_negativesemibold', sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 500; text-transform: uppercase; border: none; padding: 5px 11px 5px 9px; cursor: pointer;" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

It looks something like [this](http://www.imagesup.net/?di=214247831070).

The code to open this in pop up is given below in JS and code-behind of button click,

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#successmsg").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 230,
                width: 580,
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $('#btnClose').click(function () {
                        $("#successmsg").dialog('close');
                    });
                },
                beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                    location.href = "Career.aspx";
                }
            });
            $("#btnOk").on("click", function () {
                $("#successmsg").dialog('close');
            });
            $('.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar').css({ 'background': 'none', 'display': 'none' })
        });
```

Also see the codebehind of button click

**CODE BEHIND**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "uploaded", "$(document).ready(function(){$('#successmsg').dialog('open');});", true);
}
```

Now, Instead of div. I have a page called `Thanks.aspx` which I want to call in a pop up.

Please help, how to do this.

Comment: use jquery     $('#dialog').load('yourpath', function() {
    $(this).dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 200
    });
});

Comment: load the page with ajax

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: Can you please give it in answer, as I am not getting it.

Comment: @charlietfl: How to do that with ajax ??

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

Url string

```
var strURL="yourfilepath?string1="+string1+"&string4="+string4
```

Then use window.open()

```
 var mywindow = window.open(strURL,'','width=690,height=1000,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=10,left=200');
```

**Second method**  using jquery

```
 $('#dialog').load('yourpath', function() { $(this).dialog({ modal: true, height: 200 }); });
```

**third Method**

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string string1 = "pagename.aspx" ;
    string newWindow ="window.open('" + string1+ "');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWindow, true);
}
```

Comment: I liked your second method, but I have a question. Do i need to remove my existing javascript code for that ???

Comment: @Geeker when did you want to open a new popup ?

Comment: I want to open after the `button click`.

Comment: @Geeker then no need to worry about your javascript just write a button click event handler function in document ready and inside that put my code

Comment: @Geeker already you had done that so replace  $("#successmsg").dialog('close'); line with my code

Comment: Ok, got it.let me implement that.

Comment: @Geeker ok try , i think some ie versions does not support jquery window popup methods

Comment: But `ID` is on the same page only, so how will it call the `mypath` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71586/discussion-between-geeker-and-arunprasanth-kv).

Comment: it is a dialog box so no rpoblem with that,it will apper like a new window,i think you are telling about the div element is inside your page am i right ? that is not a problem , or if you want to open a new window then you must use window.open() methods

Comment: Yes you are right, the div is inside the page. But when I click the button click,the div is getting called instead of NewPage. I want pop up not a new window

Comment: Can you update my javascript code and put it in the answer so I can check it

Comment: @Geeker jquery popup only use your div element for storing data so no problem here ,when you run your code it will open a new popup window and it is completly looks like a new window, and the data will not apper in your current window it will apper only in popup no problem with that

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is taking the div ID of the same page which I dont want. Can you come on the chat. I will explain you better. I guess we are near to resolve this. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71586/discussion-between-geeker-and-arunprasanth-kv

Comment: Hi Arun are you their ??

Comment: @Geeker yes i am here